# Como manter os dados inseridos na View quando mudamos de página e retornamos a ela

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação onde o usuário em uma página possui várias perguntas de múltipla escolha, ele marca o radio e muda de página. Caso ele retorne novamente à página, essas opções que ele marcou devem permanecer marcadas. Alguém pode me dizer como fazer isso?

Comment: vc pode manter o estado de várias maneiras, veja se alguma te ajuda https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2 se mesmo assim não consegui, forneça algum código de modelo (View/Controller) para que possamos ajudá-lo.

Comment: ok Rafael, obrigado pela dica. Vou dar uma lida no link que você enviou e te dou retorno caso resolva o meu problema ou não. Estou precisando muito dessa ajuda e já tem mais de uma semana que não consigo dar prosseguimento no sistema que estou desenvolvendo por causa disso.

Comment: @Rafael eu já tenho a model, view e a controller feitas. Está trazendo os dados tudo certo, só falta mesmo a parte de manter os dados inseridos quando mudar de view e retornar a ela. Será que poderia dar uma ajuda? Eu inclusive postei novamente a pergunta com a model, view e controller. Quer que eu te passe a pergunta pra você dar uma olhada se poderia me dar uma ajuda?